# How to check whether camera exists in android device with Cordova?

Tags: android, camera, cordova-2.0.0

May I know how can I test for existence of camera in an android device? I want to make this option optional, so if camera is there certain functionality should work, else they should display camera is not present, so this feature is not available. or at-least hide the option if  camera is not available.

I don't want to do any Java Coding as Apache Cordova is purely javascript based. I want to check in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Try these, use the one that best suits your need and the platform you are targetting

**1) This is not so good approach as it has to open camera. But it should work,**

```
private android.hardware.Camera mCameraDevice;

try {
  mCameraDevice = android.hardware.Camera.open();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "fail to connect Camera", e);
  // Throw exception
}
```

or **this is the BEST approach**

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
}
```

or [getNumberOfCameras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getNumberOfCameras%28%29)

```
import android.hardware.Camera;

int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
if (numCameras > 0) {
  hasCamera = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I would need this in javascript to check in Cordova.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question earlier.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was mentioned in the question. I reiterated again the description for clarity.

Comment: No issues. Did you try this? navigator.hasOwnProperty('camera')

Comment: Will try it out and let you know. Thanks.